# How to display multiple Offer and price with custom text?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

In Google Rich Text SEO, I want google to display 2 offers to my product page in search as

```
Offers
$5 to $15 // the first line
Sale Price: $20 Member Price: $5 // second line



{
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"Product",
      "name":"Different retail prices same compare at prices",
      "image":"//example-img.jpg",
      "description":"V Neck top",
      "brand":{
        "@type":"Brand",
        "name":"My Brand"
      },
      "sku":"1162-BLK-XL",
      "gtin12":"",
      "offers":{
        "@type":"AggregateOffer",
        "url":"/products/XYZ",
        "priceCurrency":"USD",
        "lowPrice":"5.00",
        "highPrice": "15.00",
        "offerCount":"1",
        "itemCondition":"http://schema.org/NewCondition",
        "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
        "seller":{
          "@type":"Organization",
          "name":"XYZ"
        },
        "offers": [{
          "type": "Offer",
          "lowPrice": "Sell Price 5.00",
          "highPrice": "Member Price 3.00"
        }]
      }
    }
```

And it is showing just -
[image]

How can I achieve the above?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know Google does not support multi-line product information. And it looks like lowPrice/highPrice should be a number. I'm also not aware of any official way to define prices limited to membership.

Comment: It will be ok if it shows up in the same line. with ld+json I am having a hard time achieving it as it does not have a label or comment or tag something. Membership is just a text, it just I want to append some text before price.